# How to call servelet on button click in jsp

Tags: jsp, servlets, button

Hi I know the question is so common. I have read multiple posts also but problem is not solved yet. Thats why I am posting this question here.

I have created a menu page as per the requirement in which multiple buttons are there. and on each button click i have to call servlet path. And I am able to call that too.

But the only problem is I have to click twice to call that page. On first click I can see the servlet path on url. But on second click only that page loads.

The code that I have written is

```
<div align="left">
                <ul>
                    <li><input type="button" name="button" value="Check User" class="button" onclick="UserCreation()"/></li>

                    <li><input type="button" name="button" value="Reset Device Id" class="button" onclick="ResetDevice()"/></li>

                    <li><input type="button" name="button" value="Change Password" class="button" onclick="ChangePassword()"/></li>

                    <li><input type="button" name="button" value="User Lock" class="button" onclick="UserLock()"/></li>

                    <li><input type="button" name="button" value="Version Information" class="button" onclick="VersionInfo()"/></li>

                    <li><input type="button" name="button" value="Reset Application" class="button"/></li>

                    <li><input type="button" name="button" value="Delete User" class="button"/></li>
                </ul>
            </div>


function UserCreation()
        {
            document.Menu.action= "javascript:disableMultipleClicks(\"FECServlet?KEY=228\")";
            document.Menu.submit() ;
        }
```

Please let me know where is the mistake.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is 'Menu' here ? Is it the name of your form ?

Comment: Why don't you use hyperlinks instead of complex JavaScript buttons trying to submit a form when clicked?

Comment: Hi Menu is the jsp name. And I cant use hyperlinks because the requirement is to use buttons

Comment: Hi Saif Form name is also Menu and jsp name is also Menu

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
  document.Menu.action= "javascript:disableMultipleClicks(\"FECServlet?KEY=228\")";
```

to this

```
  document.Menu.action= "FECServlet?KEY=228";
```

i guess it should work.